# How to set scroll-lock-mode automatically for all buffers?

Tags: emacs

Added this to my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (scroll-lock-mode t)
    ))
```

It doesn't have expected result. Is it possible to have all buffers automatically open with scroll lock turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
(setq-default scroll-lock-mode 1)
```

You can turn it off with

```
(setq-default scroll-lock-mode nil)
```

Also, try the `smooth-scrolling` from ELPA/MELPA if you haven't yet.

Comment: Is this included in anything like the emacs startup hook, or just by itself in the .emacs?

Comment: by itself. Just try it from `*scratch*`